# Where can I get paid font Avenir Next LT Pro - Medium from

Tags: fonts

Can anyone please help me in finding the paid font named Avenir Next LT Pro - Medium. I searched for it but I could see only Avenir Next Pro Condensed Medium. Can anyone help from where can I purchase the Avenir Next LT Pro - Medium font only.

Answer (score 1):

[You can by it on myfonts](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/avenir-next-pro/pro-medium/) or from Linotype directly.

Comment: Hi DA01. Thanks for reply. But I still can't find the exact same font named as Avenir Next LT Pro-Medium in it.

Comment: @Designmate that's it. I believe the LT merely means "Linotype".